# Android: Application crashes when an activity is started using Intent in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialogfragment

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MytabActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

My `DialogFragment` opens when a button is clicked from the calling activity. I does what it's asked for and was able to function all the part of the code except opening to another activity after a successful response from the server (I'm using volley). The values did change but it crashes in this part.

Any ideas?

Here a screenshot of the code.

[image]

logcat:

```
03-05 03:30:11.570  16952-16952/com.example.carlajoyce.ccare E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.carlajoyce.ccare, PID: 16952
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
        at com.example.carlajoyce.ccare.UpdateDialogFragment$2$1.onResponse(UpdateDialogFragment.java:73)
        at com.example.carlajoyce.ccare.UpdateDialogFragment$2$1.onResponse(UpdateDialogFragment.java:64)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:617)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace

Comment: Stacktrace posted. thanks

Comment: try to use getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity()

Comment: According the stacktrace, your problem is not with intent, but with Toast at line 73. As @galhe2 mentioned it, the problem is probably with threads. So you can try to wrap that line in construction with runOnUiThread.

Comment: @Bashalex I commented out the Toast at line 73 for the sake of making it not crash but it still does with the Intent wrapped with runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 0):

The crash may be because you call the Intent from background thread. Make sure you are calling the Intent from Main Thread inside your Activity

Try to cast your intent inside the following:

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //INTENT HERE
    }
});
```

Comment: The IDE cannot resolve runOnUiThread because my class extends to `DialogFragment` not `Activity`

Comment: Are you able to get the context inside the DialogFragment? If yes, add it before the runOnUiThread (see edited answer)
You can get the context by calling the following: getApplicationContext()

Comment: I'm able to get the thread by `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Run.....` but the error is still there in the same spot.